# Mako fails to locate templates with TopLevelLookupException when running under gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, mako

I specify my template directory in a flask app using the following code:

```
directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "templates/")
lookup = TemplateLookup([directory])
```

This works properly when I fire up flask testing server.  It also works properly when I specify the directory manually in a python console.  For some reason, it does not work when invoked by gunicorn; instead any get_template calls fail with a TopLevelLookupException, even though the TemplateLookup is being created with the exact same directory list as when manually run.

I'd love any ideas.  I've already verified that it is not a permission issue by running gunicorn as root, verifying root has read privileges, and verifying that the scripts returned 0 from os.getuid().

Comment: When you say it does not work, in what way? Does it throw an exception? If so, can you add it to the question?

Comment: It fails with a TopLevelLookupException as mentioned in the question title.  The message that is included is roughly along the lines of "Cant locate template for uri 'template.mako'"

Comment: Is it possible you have the directory right but are requesting the wrong template in the production environment? If you'll add some code and the actual exception to your question that will give folks more information to work with.